# How do I disable the text/icon shade on the GNOME top panel?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome, panel, gnome-panel

When I maximize an application and unmaximize it with a custom GNOME theme, some of the shading in the GNOME top panel [is inconsistent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuTDi.png).

But when I mouse over them they [fix themselves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0evw.png).

[(Here are the images side by side to anyone struggling to see the difference)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvcnD.png)

Honestly, I don't really care about it, I'd just like it to be consistent. That said, is there a way I can disable it/fix it?

Comment: I couldn't see it in the side-by-side, but opening 2 tabs for the other 2 images and flicking between them shows the very subtly change - which seems to me to be in icon shadow and icon opacity.

Comment: Do you have settings that change opacity with focus, and something like "focus follows mouse" enabled?

Comment: @pbhj Nope, haven't changed except for the icon theme.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which one was at fault, but this appears to be fixed in a newer version of GNOME or the icon theme I use (Papirus) :)

Still not sure how to manually disable the shade though, maybe a GNOME extension could be the answer.